# $(document).ready and $('#id').change produce different results

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

[Site here](http://www.guestvibe.com/index.php).

Why is it that the code works for `$('#club').change(function(event)` but not for `$(document).ready(function()`? The `$.ajax` functions are identical, but the former simply does nothing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "eventinfo.php",
            data:  $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#right_inside').html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '<span style="font-size: 14px"> (' + data[0].day + ')</h2><p>Entry: ' + data[0].entry + '</p><p>Queue jump: ' + data[0].queuejump + '</p><p>Guestlist closes at ' + data[0].closing + '</p>');
                },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });

    $('#club').change(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "eventinfo.php",
            data:  $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#right_inside').html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '<span style="font-size: 14px"> (' + data[0].day + ')</h2><p>Entry: ' + data[0].entry + '</p><p>Queue jump: ' + data[0].queuejump + '</p><p>Guestlist closes at ' + data[0].closing + '</p>');
                },
            dataType: "json"
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Show your HTML. Also, explain how it's "not working". Error message?

Comment: I've had a look at the page, when the user selects `Let's kill disco @ Lola Lo` nothing happens. So, I get the feeling that it's not a problem with your jquery, it's a problem with the entry in your `#club` select box.

Comment: The "id" values of your elements must not contain spaces.

Comment: @Pointy Technically correct, though it appears it may be doing the job needed. 

@ Sebastian Because we can't see eventinfo.php, we can't see or comment on the workings of it. Perhaps your issue is it's simply reading the data wrong?

Comment: The apostrophe in `Let's` has given me problems elsewhere. Might this be it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request is made. That is easy to verify by checking the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools. It returns an empty array such that `data = []`. So `data[0].day` throws an error and that error isn't caught.

The difference between the two blocks of code is what's is contained in the variable `this`. In the first one it is a jQuery object containing your `document`. In the second one it is a jquery object containing the `<select>` element with the id `club`. Since you want to serialize the same element in your `$(document).ready` all you have to do is change `$(this)` to `$(#club)`.

Comment: I just tried this but it doesn't work. Are there any other disparities that might be causing problems?

Comment: @SebastianSalek Well you did fix the error, so it is now posting the data to the server correctly on document ready. But there is another error (server side) where `Let's Kill Disco @ Lola Lo` is not recognized. Although all the other entries in your dropdown are.

Comment: @SebastianSalek For all the other entries in your dropdown a JSON array containing a single object (with contents) is returned. For the first entry an empty array is returned and you'll get an error. You'll notice that if you switch away from that first entry and then back, nothing changes on your page either. That's because of the Javascript error.

Comment: Unofrunately I can't help more than that, because the reason that `Let's Kill Disco @ Lola Lo` returns an empty array is in your server side code, not it your Javascript.

Comment: I think I know the problem - sometimes `Let's` echoes as `Let/'s`. It's probably doing that here and so the match isn't being found. Is there a way to counter this?

Answer (score 2):

What is it that you expect `$(this)` to refer to in the "ready' handler? In the "change" handler, it's that "#club" element. In the "ready" handler, it will be something probably useless.

Instead of `$(this).serialize()` I think you want `$('#club').serialize()` in the "ready" handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your HTML code.

```
<select id="club" class="dropdown" name="club">
    <option id="Let" lo'="" lola="" @="" disco="" kill="" s="">Let's Kill Disco @ Lola Lo</option>
    <option id="Fuzzy Logic @ The Place">Fuzzy Logic @ The Place</option>
    <option id="BOOM! @ The Place">BOOM! @ The Place</option>
    <option id="Fuzzy Logic @ Ballare">Fuzzy Logic @ Ballare</option>
    <option id="Jelly Baby @ Ballare">Jelly Baby @ Ballare</option>
    <option id="Fiesta @ Fez">Fiesta @ Fez</option>
</select>
```

Look at the first entry. It doesn't work because the ID doesn't exist, and the tags are all messed up. Ensure that you're escaping your quotes when you add your events to your list. When you do that, your jQuery `$.ajax` request should work fine.

Comment: Although that is an issue and should be fixed as well it doesn't solve the problem because jquery Serialize doesn't use `id`s.

Comment: True, but once serialized and deserialized, perhaps if the `eventinfo.php` can't return a proper result, it returns nothing. But seeing as the whole thing is serialized, it's certainly worth fixing.